# Join two tables with same rows in SQL

Tags: python, sql

Suppose I have two table like this:

```
table 1:               table 2:
id      city           id      heading
1201     X             1201     A
1202     Y             1201     B
1203     Z             1202     C
1204     U             1202     D
                       1204     F
```

I want Output like this:

```
id  city id  heading
1201 X   1201  A
*null*   1201  B
1202 Y   1202  C
*null*   1202  D
1203 Z   *null*
1204 U   1204 F
```

Kindly Help me with this.

Python is also acceptable if possible.

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.

Comment: select * from table1 join table2  on table1.id=table2.User_ID;

Comment: Also try in Python:   result=pd.concat([df_table1,df_table2],axis=1,join_axes=[df_table2.User_ID])

Comment: is it important to have `NULL` in the left column of your output if there are actually matches in your second table?

Comment: No if there is match , then no null

Comment: @Jitesh Your data is such that no sqlite join will do.. The existence of duplicates in table 2 is killing it. I would suggest fetching the data and writing some patch code for that

Comment: @Ev.Kounis If possible in any other language that would be also helpful. How do I do in excel if any one know ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `full outer join` :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: this generates `1201 X 1201  B` which is not wanted by OP

Answer (score 0):

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` is the way to go, but you also need a sequence number:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: What is sequence number ? and will this be working in mysql 5.7

Comment: @Jitesh . . . This is ANSI standard SQL, which works in most databases, but not all.